# Unsupervised machine learning with scikit learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning

I am learning about unsupervised machine learning with scikit learn. I have collected so data from online. when I try to apply scatter plot I am getting following error

> IndexingError: Too many indexers

Here is the code:

```
data = arff.loadarff("./Data/Arrhythmia/Arrhythmia_withoutdupl_02_v01.arff")
df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])
df = df.drop(['outlier',"id"],axis=1)
X_com = df.att10
plt.scatter(X_com.iloc[:,0],X_com.iloc[:,1])
plt.show()
```

I want to apply here `KMeans` algorithm from scikit learn. What I am doing wrong ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you want to see the spread of data, with respect to first two features. Then you have to slice it from the initial dataset instead from Series (as @Alexandre metioned)

```
data = arff.loadarff("./Data/Arrhythmia/Arrhythmia_withoutdupl_02_v01.arff")
df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])
df = df.drop(['outlier',"id"],axis=1)
plt.scatter(df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,1])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

X_com is a pd.Series, so when you're trying to slice it using .iloc, you can only specify one axis.